# "Ich komme gerade + Land" (keine Herkunft)

Tags: preposition

Wenn man über die Herkunft spricht, benutzt man die Präposition *aus*:

> Ich komme aus den Niederlanden/ den USA/ der Türkei.

Ich gehe nun vom Satz *Ich komme gerade vom Friseur* aus: Wäre die Präposition *von* richtig im folgenden Satz?

> Ich komme gerade von den Niederlanden/ den USA/ der Türkei, wo ich
> Urlaub gemacht habe.

Wenn man am Flughafen landet und gefragt wird, woher man gerade gekommen ist, sagt man "*Ich komme aus Australien*." oder "Ich komme (zurück) von Australien"? (Der Reisende ist kein Australier.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Da gibt es keinen Unterschied. Wenn man von einem Ort her kommt, ist das per Definition eine Herkunft. Egal, ob man dort geboren und aufgewachsen ist, oder ob man dort nur kurz zum Shoppen war.

Natürlich hat das Wort *»Herkunft«* selbst, zumindest im Fall von Personen, die primäre Bedeutung *»Ort an dem man aufgewachsen ist«.* Das ändert aber genau gar nichts an den Präpositionen. Die Frage lautet auch in beiden Fällen gleich: *»Wo kommst du her?«* Wenn man nach dem Ort der Kindheit fragen will, ist es daher auch besser nicht zu fragen woher man *kommt,* sondern woher man *ist.* (*»Von wo bist du?«*) Oder noch eindeutiger: *»Wo bist du aufgewachsen?«*

Wenn man vorher ***in*** einem Ort war und diesen Ort dann verlässt, dann kommt man immer ***aus*** diesem Ort:

> Wo kommst du her? - Aus der Küche.
> Wo kommst du her? - Aus der Schweiz.
> Wo kommst du her? - Aus dem Wald.
> Wo kommst du her? - Aus dem Iran.

Bei Ländern und anderen geographischen Regionen ist nur anders, dass die meisten von ihnen ohne Artikel verwendet werden, das hat aber keinen Einfluss auf die Präposition:

> Wo kommst du her? - Aus Afrika.
> Wo kommst du her? - Aus Frankreich.
> Wo kommst du her? - Aus München.

Anders ist das, wenn der Ort etwas ist, **auf** oder **bei** dem man sich befinden kann, dann kommt man anschließend **von** dort.

> Ich war gerade **bei** dem (=beim) Frisör. Ich komme gerade **von** dem (=vom) Friseur.
> Ich war heute Mittag **auf** dem Schneeberg. Ich komme gerade  **von** dem (=vom) Schneeberg.

Man kann z.B. **auf** Inseln sein:

> Wo kommst du her? - Von Rügen.

Auch bei dieser Antwort weiß man nicht, ob die antwortende Person auf Rügen aufgewachsen ist, oder ob sie gerade von einem Rügen-Kurztrip zurückgekommen ist.

Wenn jemand sagt, er käme gerade *von* den Niederlanden, dann müsste er vorher *auf* oder *bei* den Niederlanden gewesen sein, das sind aber unübliche Präpositionen um den Aufenthalt **in** einem Land zu beschrieben, daher ist auch »*von* den Niederlanden« falsch. (Dasselbe gilt für die anderen in der Frage genannten Beispiele.)

Wenn man also unmittelbar nach dem Heimflug vom Australienurlaub direkt am Flughafen gefragt wird *»Wo kommst du her?«,* dann lautet die richtige Antwort: »*Ich komme gerade **aus** Australien«.* Wenn man Missverständnisse vermeiden will, kann man auch etwas in dieser Art sagen:

> Ich bin Schwedin und kehre gerade von meinem Urlaub in Australien zurück.

Comment: Oder: "Ich bin eine in Litauen als Tochter kenianischer Eltern geborene Schwedin mit Wohnsitz in Deutschland und komme gerade per Flug mit Zwischenlandung in Hongkong aus Australien zurück, wo ich Urlaub von meiner Arbeit in den Niederlanden bei einer französichen Firma machte ... was war nochmal die Frage?"

Answer (score 3):

Es ist auch in diesem Fall "aus". Du bist *in* den Niederlanden und kommst dann *aus* den Niederlanden. Du bist *beim* Friseur und kommst dann *vom* Friseur.

Comment: Das "gerade" macht den Unterschied